# Sensiolabs/Symfony duplicated components: Which ones should I use?

Tags: symfony, php-5.3

Pimple or Container?

http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/

http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/

Twig or Template?

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

http://components.symfony-project.org/templating/

I'm not asking for an opinion, I just want to know this:

- Why are these components being distributed with different names?
- Which ones are newer?
- Which are the ones being used by symfony 2 ?
- Is there a list for components like Pimple and Twig? Like there is for Container and Template: http://components.symfony-project.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 categories of projects you have listed.

1. Third-party library. While provided by sensiolabs, these are standalone libraries not under the symfony namespace.
2. Old Symfony 1.x components, also standalone but under the Symfony namespace. Available at [components.symfony-project.org](http://components.symfony-project.org), compatible with PHP 5.2.
3. Symfony2 components, part of [the Symfony2 package](http://symfony.com), but can also be used standalone. Compatible with PHP 5.3+.

Ok, so let's categorize the projects you've listed.

### Category 1

- Pimple
- Twig

There is currently no Pimple bundle for Symfony2. The recommended way to go with is to use the Symfony2 DependencyInjection component, which ships with the framework.

Note: Pimple is heavily used by [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org), so if you like Pimple, you might want to take a look at it. It's a different framework that is based on Symfony2 components.

Twig, on the other hand, is supported very well by the Symfony2 core framework. There is a core Bundle for it, and most of the documentation suggests you use it. It is definitely the recommended way to do templating in Symfony2.

For a list of more of these, take a look at [Fabien Potencier's GitHub profile](https://github.com/fabpot). IMO the important ones are: Twig, Silex, Pimple, Goutte, (Pirum, Sismo).

## Category 2

- Symfony Components DependencyInjection
- Symfony Components Templating

These are old and should no longer be used.

## Category 3

- Symfony2 DependencyInjection Component
- Symfony2 Templating Component
- Symfony2 Twig Bundle

These are all part of the Symfony2 framework, and you should use them. They are the latest and greatest.

Hope that answers your questions!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could use http://components.symfony-project.org components if you have some kind of legacy project that uses php 5.2 or your server has php older than 5.3.

I have a project, I' m doing some rewriting, but it's legacy php 5.2 so I decited to use the old components (http://components.symfony-project.org) instead of new symfony's 2.0 components